# Getting the latest build id from a referenced pipeline resource

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In the classic release pipeline it was possible to add other pipelines as Artifact resources - these could be triggers, or just references. You could then reference information about them, e.g. the build id using `$(Release.Artifacts.ARTIFACTNAME.BuildId)`.

You can now do [something similar](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/improved-continuous-delivery-capabilities-and-caching-for-azure-pipelines/) in a multi-stage yaml pipeline:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyBuild
    source: My build pipeline name 
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Write-Host Referenced pipeline build id is: ???
```

But as per the PowerShell step above, I can't find a way to get the build id of a resource associated in this way, and I can't spot anything in the documentation yet.

Some desperate attempts I've made are:

```bsh
$(Release.Artifacts.MyBuild.BuildId)
$(resources.MyBuild.BuildId)
$(BuildId@MyBuild)
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Just a wild guess, could it be `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release-variables

Comment: Thanks @YanSklyarenko - good guess, but I haven't been able to get any of the Release.* parameters working in a yaml pipeline. The other limitation would be that you can have multiple resources configured, and any of them could be the trigger, or none if it was manually triggered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The newest release notes has a new set of predefined variables.

```
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.projectName 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.projectID 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.pipelineName 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.pipelineID 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.runName 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.runID
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.runURI
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.sourceBranch 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.sourceProvider 
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.{Alias}.requestedForID
```

See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-160-update#pipeline-resource-meta-data-as-predefined-variables

Comment: That looks spot on. I'll have a play when I'm back at work and update this to be the accepted answer to confirm

Comment: Also, I was frustratingly close with one of my wild guesses!

Comment: Ok, our tenant is still on the sprint 159 deployment so I'll take it on trust that this is going to work given it's in the documentation!

Comment: @MikeGoatly yeah you were really close. I stumbled over the documentation trying to implement build/deploy piplines for our project only moments before I read your question. :)

Comment: 160 was finally rolled out to our instance and... it didn't work. However, give i was so close with my random guesses previously, I guessed some more and it turns out that the variables are case sensitive and incorrect in the release notes. Instead of `resources.pipeline.{Alias}.runID` use `Resources.Pipeline.{Alias}.RunID` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, Build.BuildId matches exactly to $(resources.pipeline.{Alias}.RunID)

Answer (score 4):

It seems the referenced resources' information can not be fetched directly. 
A workaround is using powershell task calling [Restful Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get those information. Please refer to below:

```
steps: 
- powershell: |
    $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?includeLatestBuilds=true&api-version=5.1"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Get
    $buildId = $result.latestBuild.id
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildId;isOutput=true]$buildId" #set a variable to refer to the buildid 
  name: setvarStep

#get the variable set in above task.
- script: |
    echo $(setvarStep.buildId)
```

Above example get the id of lastbuild by calling restful api, and use script `##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildId;isOutput=true]$buildId"` to output it to the following task.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for more information about how to set variables in yaml pipeline.

However if you are not satisfied with this workaround, you can go [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit a feature request for this case, or report a problem.

[image]

Comment: Nice - it looks like I can make that work. I hadn't thought about using the REST APIs to work around it - that's smart.

Comment: The only modifications I've made to the script are to make it a bit more generic so I can template it up and re-use it across definitions: `$url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?name=$(buildname)&includeLatestBuilds=true&api-version=5.1"` and `$buildId = $result.value[0].latestBuild.id`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As JohannesH has pointed out, once Sprint 160 hits your tenant, this will be possible with new predefined variables, so using the REST api is overkill.

I'm leaving this answer here in case anyone finds it necessary to do something similar with the REST API in a template.

---

Based on Levi's <strike>accepted</strike> answer I put together a template that can be re-used:

```
parameters:
  buildName:
  outputVariable:

steps:
- powershell: |
    $url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?name=${{ parameters.buildName }}&includeLatestBuilds=true&api-version=5.1"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Get
    $buildId = $result.value[0].latestBuild.id
    echo "Determined latest build id for ${{ parameters.buildName }} as $buildId"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameters.outputVariable }}]$buildId"
  name: Get${{ parameters.outputVariable }}
  displayName: Get latest build id for ${{ parameters.buildName }}
```

And an example of this re-use:

```
variables:
  build1: My Build Name
  build2: Another Build Name

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Build1
    source: My Build Name
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master
  - pipeline: Build2
    source: Another Build Name
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master

steps:
- template: yaml-templates/get-build-id.yml
  parameters:
    buildName: $(build1)
    outputVariable: build1Id
- template: yaml-templates/get-build-id.yml
  parameters:
    buildName: $(build2)
    outputVariable: build2Id
- powershell: |
    echo "Build 1 id: $(build1Id) Build 2 id: $(build2Id)"
  name: EchoBuildIds
```

Notes:

1. It doesn't look like source names of `resources` can be variables, so there's a bit of duplication as far as the build names goes.
2. I'm setting job-scoped variables in the template, that's not a problem for me, but could be for you - YMMV!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
echo $(resources.pipeline.MyBuild.runID)
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit late to the show. I access the `BuildId` within the pipeline like so:

```
jobs:
    - job: MyJob
      steps:
          - bash: |
              echo "Test Id: $(Build.BuildId)"
```

see docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tokens

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PowerShell task to get the Build Id from your triggering artifact.

```
$alias = "$(Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias)"
$buildIdKey = "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_" + $alias + "_BUILDID"
$buildId = (Get-item env:$buildIdKey).Value
```