# How can I download the last successful build using DownloadPipelineArtifact

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need to fetch a particular file from another build pipeline, and I'm doing it like this:

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: 'Fetch my thing'
    inputs:
      source: specific
      project: 'OtherProject'
      pipeline: pipeid
      runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'
      runBranch: 'refs/heads/master'
      checkDownloadedFiles: true
      tags: 'int'
      patterns: mypattern
      path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Most of the time, this works great.  But if the most recent tagged version of the OtherProject build has failed, then this task fails as well.

What I *want* is to download from the last **successful** 'int' tagged build, not just the last tagged build, and I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task looks ok to me, so if that does not work, I'd first go and check whether you have a trigger for the OtherProject in the pipeline and if so, include the tag in that trigger. So:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build_other_project
    source: OtherProject 
    trigger:
      branches:
      - master
      tags:
      - int
```

And changing the download reference to something like this:

```
project: "$(resources.pipeline.build_other_project.projectID)"
definition: "$(resources.pipeline.build_other_project.pipelineID)"
```

If it's not feasible for the OtherProject to trigger this pipeline, then you might have to query the buildid for the latest succesful build with tag 'int' via REST API. So something akin to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770273/11034408

And then in the download-task something like :

```
buildVersionToDownload: "specific"
runId: "$(build1Id)"
```

Comment: I had to query the build ID via the REST API, but I did get it to work.  Thanks!